# Оптимизировать архитектуру таблиц и запросы в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть три таблицы:

```
tbl_комплекс                tbl_тест                 tbl_услуга
код комплекса (INT)         код теста(INT)           код услуги (INT) 
наименование комплекса      наименование теста       наименование услуги
                                                     код (комплекса/услуги)
```

`tbl_комлекс` и `tbl_тест` связаны между собой как многие ко многим (с этим проблем нет).

А вот `tbl_услуга` связана как с `tbl_комплекс`, так и с `tbl_тест` - код (комплекса/услуги) соответствует таковому из `tbl_комплекс` или `tbl_тест` (при этом одна услуга соответствует либо одному комплексу, либо одному тесту.

`Услуга` - это данные хранимые в 1С. То, что продает клиентам предприятие. `Комплекс` и `Тест` - это то, что производит предприятие (оказывает услуги). Например: `Услуга` "Гликированный гемоглобин" включает в себя один `Тест`. `Услуга` "Общий анализ крови" включает в себя множество `Тестов` (концентрация гемоглобина, количество эритроцитов, лейкоцитов и т.д.) в этом случае необходимо создавать `Комплекс`, состоящий из тестов, входящих в него. В данном случае `Услуга` - это `комплекс`.

Мой вопрос в том, как лучше представить такую связь? Как лучше построить запрос, который будет по коду услуги тянуть соответствующие поля из теста или из комплекса, при этом если это комплекс, то должны тянуться соответствующие ему тесты?

Comment: Связь многие ко многим сделать через таблицу `комплекс-тест` и привязать `tbl_услуга` к ней?

Comment: Если услуга соответствует либо тесту, либо комплексу (но не их сочетанию), то лучше будет разбить `tbl_услуга` на 2 разных таблицы `услуга_комплекса` и `услуга_теста`. Иначе вы не сможете идентифицировать к чему будет относиться код.

Comment: Гм... а почему Комплекс и Тест являются двумя разными сущностями? Всё написанное **пока** позволяет утверждать, что это может оказаться одна и та же сущность, просто у неё есть ещё дополнительный атрибут типа со значениями Комплекс и Тест.

Comment: @matrix спасибо, надо будет подумать над Вашим вторым предложением, но tbl_услуга - данные тянутся из другой системы и не могут быть выгружены как "комплекс" или "тест". Только если ручками потом определять, что из них к чему относится. А по первому - тест не всегда входит в комплекс.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, это бы сработало, но я не уточнил, что tbl_комплекс и tbl_тест могут иметь одинаковые коды (плохо конечно, но так данные уже заведены и ,к сожалению, ничего с этим не поделать), ну и у них есть еще различные атрибуты, которые к вопросу не имели отношения, потому и не указал.

Comment: @ДмитрийФайзулин так вам тогда нужно еще автоинкрементируемый `id` добавить в каждую из таблиц и использовать его в качестве ключа, а не `код`

Comment: @ДмитрийФайзулин вообще, опишите, пожалуйста более подробно предметную область. Например, что такое `комплекс` - это группа `тестов`? В таком случае `услуга комплекса` - это `услуга по группе тестов`? Приведите также пример данных, которые вы получаете.

Comment: @matrix, Услуга - данные хранимые в 1С - то, что продает клиентам предприятие. Комплекс и Тест - то, что производит предприятие (оказывает услуги). Например: Услуга "Гликированный гемоглобин" - включает в себя один Тест (на оборудовании производится поиск значения показателя "гликированный гемоглобин"). Услуга "Общий анализ крови" - включает в себя множество Тестов (концентрация гемоглобина, количество эритроцитов, лейкоцитов и т.д.) в этом случае необходимо создавать Комплекс, состоящий из тестов, входящих в него и в данном случае Услуга - это комплекс.

Comment: @ДмитрийФайзулин А услуга может содержать одновременно и отдельный тест и какой-либо комплекс?

Comment: @matrix, нет, либо 1 комплекс, либо 1 тест.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так.

1. Связь между тестом и комплексом нужно представить в виде таблицы `Комплекс-Тест`.
2. В таблице `Услуга` нужно разделить поле `Код` на `Код_услуги` и `Код_комплекса`.
3. Добавить во все таблицы уникальные поля id

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда запрос для получения кода теста/комплекса по коду услуги будет иметь вид:

```
SELECT t.code
FROM TEST t
WHERE t.id in (SELECT s.test.id 
                FROM Service s
                WHERE s.code = <input_code>)
UNION 

SELECT t.code
FROM TEST t
LEFT JOIN Complex_Test ct on t.id = ct.test_id
WHERE ct.complex_id in (SELECT s.complex_id 
                        FROM Service s
                        WHERE s.code = <input_code>);
```

Comment: спасибо! такой вариант действительно хорошо решает мою проблему.